# conversationUpdate event not getting user input

Tags: node.js, botframework

I use following method to ask question by bot when user connects first time. But after user answering the question, instead of going to next step bot goes to new dialog.

This works fine with emulator, but not with directline api.

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
            if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
                bot.beginDialog(message.address, '/startConversation');
            }
        });
    }
});

bot.dialog('/startConversation', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'I\'m the SPF VA Assistant. How may I address you?');
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.userData.name = results.response;
        session.send('Hi, %s, Please choose one of the options below to lodge a Police report.', session.userData.name);
        var cards = getReportsAsCards();
        var reportOptions = new builder.Message(session)
            .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
            .attachments(cards);
        session.send(reportOptions).endDialog();
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you send the question "Please choose one of the options below..." you are calling `endDialog()`.  This is what causes it to go to the new dialog like you said.

If you want to [prompt the user for input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt), use a [Choice Prompt](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.__global.iprompts.html#choice), and add another step in your waterfall dialog to handle the user's choice input.

For example, to get the user's name, first ask the question using a text prompt, then handle the user's response in step 2 of the waterfall dialog. The user's response text will be available in the `results.response` object in step 2.

```
bot.dialog('greetings', [
    // Step 1
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
    },
    // Step 2
    function (session, results) {
        session.endDialog('Hello %s!', results.response);
    }
]);
```

To prompt the user with a series of choices use a waterfall dialog combined with a `builder.Prompts.choice()` call. For example:

```
var noiseComplaintName = "Noise Complaint";
var trashDumpingName = "Trash Dumping";
var weirdSmellName = "Weird Smell";
var trafficSignalName = "Traffic Signal";

var reportTypes = [
    noiseComplaintName,
    trashDumpingName,
    weirdSmellName,
    trafficSignalName
];

bot.dialog('pick-report-type', [
    function(session) {
        session.send('Choice prompt example:');

        var promptOptions = {
            listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button
        };

        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "What do you want to report?", reportTypes, promptOptions);
    },
    function (session, results) {
        // handle response from choice prompt
        var selectedReportType = results.response.entity;

        switch (selectedReportType) {
            case noiseComplaintName:
                // handle response here
                break;
            case trashDumpingName:
                // handle response here
                break;
            case weirdSmellName:
                // handle response here
                break;
            case trafficSignalName:
                // handle response here
                break;
            default
                // handle response here
                break;
        }
    }
]);
```

For a more detailed example that combines prompts with [Rich Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards), check out the sample code: [BotBuilder-Samples/Node/cards-RichCards](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-RichCards) on GitHub.